# Vbscipt error while creating a named pipe

Tags: ipc, pipe

I am new to vbscript as well as to  named pipes.

This is my code:

```
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("\\.\pipe\tstpipe")
a.WriteLine("This is a test.")
msgbox "hello"
a.Close
```

Error "File not found ,line 2"
Its not recognizing folder "pipe" as I have not created any folder with name pipe.But I think there should be a default folder with the name pipe. Am i correct?
Am i missing any configuration for pipe?

Answer (score 0):

CreateTextFile("\.\pipe\tstpipe", true);